# interface constants not initialized at runtime in implementing classes

Tags: java, spring, interface, constants

I have an interface where constants are defined using
`static final Repsonse = new Response(...)`.
These constants are used (or rather: should be used) by the methods defined in the interface as return values.

Now I have Spring instantiate the classes that implement this interface but these constants are not initiated (they are `null`) when the application is run.

Is this a general issue with interfaces or is it something that is specific to Spring?
Maybe there is a better way to achieve the intended functionality?

For those of you who need mroe information:
The interface defines a "checker" that defines several different methods to check states of objects. Each of these methods is expected to return a standardized `Response` object which is a simple container with standardized information about the state of the object that is being inspected by the method.
I thougth it was a good idea to define all possible response codes as constants so implementers who use the interface had them right at hand. Maybe I am wrong?

Here are some code snippets:

```
public interface Validator
{
    static final Response VALID = new Response(some params);

    /** is expected to return the Response VALID */
    Response validate(String param1, String param2);
}

public class ValidatorImpl implements Validator
{
    public Response validate(String param1, String param2)
    {
        //VALID is null; also tried explicit static access here, no luck either
        return VALID;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Could you please post some original snippets, maybe someone find a bug in it.

Comment: I just tried a standalone program and it works well. In fact spring recommends interface based approach. It should work. That static variables are initialized at the class load time itself.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! You encouraged me to write a small test using an explicit constructor approach instead of injecting with Spring and indeed it's working this way. So I guess there is an error somewhere else, I will have a look at my Spring integration.

Comment: @m00hk00h: you wrote in your comment"...  using an explicit constructor approach instead of injecting with Spring and indeed it's working this way." --- does you mean, that the problem and the code you posted was not the one use used; instead you used `@Inject` or `@Autowired` for the static variables in the interface?

Comment: @Ralph No, what I meant is I called the Validator class with new() instead of injecting the class in a variable using Spring. I have just found the error, though: I made a mistake in the "getInstance()" method used to handle the singleton instance of that class, it's working as intended now. Wouldn't have looked at that code without your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If anyone wants to ceate an answer stating that there is nothing wrong with this code, then I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to initialize constants in interfaces, but it is generally considered to be an anti-pattern despite being used in the Java libraries themselves. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface

You may want to consider the following. If the Response object is simple and you just want to be able to differentiate between different levels of validity, create an enum for this outside your interface:

```
public enum Validity
{
    VALID, INVALID
}

public interface Validator
{
    Validity validate(String param1, String param2);
}

public class ValidatorImpl implements Validator
{
    public Validity validate(String param1, String param2)
    {
        return Validity.VALID;
    }
}
```

If you want to add more state to your responses (such as a description) I recommend initializing them in your config file, adding them to a map and injecting the map into your implementing classes as follows, with the value type as your "Response" type from earlier. The map below is an EnumMap, which uses the Validity enum as a key.

```
<util:map id="validityMap">
  <entry key="#{T(com.acme.Validity).VALID}" value-ref="valid" />
  <entry key="#{T(com.acme.Validity).INVALID}" value-ref="invalid" />
</util:map>

<bean id="valid" class="com.acme.Response">
    <property name="comment" value="This is valid" />
</bean>

<bean id="invalid" class="com.acme.Response">
    <property name="comment" value="This is invalid" />
</bean>

public enum Validity
{
    VALID, INVALID
}

public interface Validator
{
    Response validate(String param1, String param2);
}

public class ValidatorImpl implements Validator
{
    // Inject from config (remember to add getter and setter)
    private validityMap;

    public Response validate(String param1, String param2)
    {
        return getValidityMap().get(Validity.VALID);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but it answers the question to "how to prevent constant interfaces" which was never my problem. The constants are just part of the interface, there are plenty of different methods defined with extensive javadoc for implementers. And since the API is not public I don't consider it a problem over the easy of providing additional information. I am totally aware of the problem though - in fact, I made extensive use of enums in the Response object itself.